# Explaining concepts

Tags: patterns-and-practices, anti-patterns

How can I explain a concept when I don't know its name or any formal reason for it? The reason I ask is this...

A new programmer has entities with a property title in his system. He uses the title to derive image paths. Then we discovered that the titles weren't the same case as the actual paths. His environment (more specifically his server) serve the images case insensitive and my lamp stack doesn't. This was basically the problem.

When I explained to him that it would be wise to not derive the images name from the title but instead he should include a property entity.image-path he didn't get it and was annoyed that I told him to change his program. He says he can just lower case the title while deriving the images path. He hadn't yet noticed that all his titles are upper case words and some of the images upper case and some lower so his idea of transforming the title won't work.

But how do I explain the general idea that he should never have been trying to derive an image file name from a string that is used for a html page title and could be changed for seo or usability reasons without sounding in anyway patronising. This accusation made at me when I said "now I've been programming a while and I'm sure it should be done the way I know it should be done."

Comment: recommended reading: **[How do I explain ${something} to ${someone}?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6630/31260)**

Comment: You are calling it a "property title" which connotates that your co-worker is misusing the field. Is that the actual name of the property "Title"? If not then is it possible that you are viewing the property "title" as simply a title while your co-worker views it as a "key". In that case, your co-worker isn't wrong.  If that's the case then you are both right and both wrong at the same time. That's why it is a good idea to write a data interface document when multiple developers are exchanging data over an interface. If you had that then at least one of you would have been obviously wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Requirement Documents and Unit tests.

You can argue until the end of days about architecture and best practice, but its all basically opinion unless you agree on some fundamental principle you can argue from.

The thing you cant argue about is 'does the program fulfil the requirement?' this is simply provable one way or the other as long as the requirement is well defined.

In this case you might have a requirement which says:

- 'The Title should be able to contain any UTF8 character, including spaces, 
  single quotes, new lines, foreign languages and accents'

and another which says :

- 'The file path must only contain ASCII characters excluding white-space etc etc and must be less than 256 characters'

You can then write a test case or cases to prove the solution matches the requirements. If it fails you need to change it. If the 'crazy' ad-hoc trick works, you don't.

Answer (score 0):

In the concrete case, the thing to do is to point out that a solution is *incorrect* by supplying a case where it does the wrong thing. This is what you did.

But what if someone then adds ad-hoc trickery that fixes this case but will obviously fail for the next slightly different case you could come up with? You're right that to explain *why* an ad-hoc solution doesn't work in the general case, oyu should usually try to find the *name* of the concept you're talking about, and use that in your argument.

In your case, the problem seems to be with *subtly different data types*. This is a problem that occurs particularly often with character strings and things that are almost, but not quite, like strings. In this case, the fact that some components of the system distinguish case and others don't was the problem. At other places it might be the fact that only a certain subset of the defined characters is actually permissible, and things won't blow up until someone introduces one of the "rare" characters. (For instance, UNIX has a deep-seated problem with strings that work fine *as long as there's no whitespace in them*, and an even deeper-seated problem with strings that work fine **as long as neither \0 nor / is in them**.)

Because such subtle problems almost always occur when you model something that isn't really a fully general string as a string, it is almost always a good idea to create a special-purpose type that does all the checking that is *actually* required to use a piece of data safely, and use that in place of a raw string. Unfortunately, the only technical term I know for the issue is "stringly typed", but that describes the problem rather than the solution!